# How can I traverse down from grandparent to first child first grandchild in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have markup like this,

```
 <div class="new-content">
    <div>
        <button><span class="fa fa-xxx"></span></button>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-div">
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to change the text of span tag `<span>Some text here</span>` using jquery.
I used `$('.new-content').children('div').first().children('span').first().text(''some other text');` to change the text, but I'm worried about code efficiency. If you know better way to do this, please answer.

Comment: Can you add a class or id to span?

Comment: `$('.new-content div > span')` or `$('.new-content span:not(.fa)')`.  Lots of ways to do this

Comment: @Taplar chuck some `:first-child`s in there, and that'll be perfect!

Comment: @Joundill no need for first child.  There is only one div that is a child that has a span as a direct child.  The other span is a direct child of a button

Comment: @Taplar What happens if the html changes? Your CSS selector won't be equivalent to the js the asker has written.

Comment: If the html changes beyond any certain point, the selector would have to be re-evaluated anyway.  I get your point that selectors should be made to be as resillient as possible.  My comment is intended to be more around the "Lots of ways to do this" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select using CSS instead of chaining jQuery like so:

```js
jQuery(".new-content > div:first-child > span:first-of-type").text("Replace text");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-content">
    <div>
        <button><span class="fa fa-xxx"></span></button>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-div">
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from client selection query like this : `$(".new-content>div:first>span")`

```js
var tsx = $(".new-content>div:first>span").text();
$("#resul").html(tsx);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="new-content">
    <div>
        <button><span class="fa fa-xxx">Hello</span></button><br>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-div">
    mdmdmdm
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="resul">
 \sdff
 </div>
```